# Spring consumes json or xml

Tags: xml, json, spring, spring-mvc

i'm trying to find a correct tutorial to learn how to let spring consume json or xml.

I've got a bean like:

```
public class MyBean{
   private String id;
   private String name;
   private MyBeanValues values;
   //get and set
}

public class MyBeanValues{
   private List<MyBeanValue> values;
   //get and set
}
public class MyBeanValue{
   private String id;
   private String name;
   //get and set
}
```

What i would like to do is to create a controller which accept xml or json and automatically map into that bean,something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "search", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/json", "application/xml" })
public @ResponseBody String search(@ModelAttribute MyBean mybean) {
   return mybean.getValues().get(0).getId();
}
```

Even if i pass an xml or json rappresenting my bean structure, spring needs to convert it correctly.

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>ws</artifactId>
    <name>myTest</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Moxy JAXB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Reactor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-rc2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-rc2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mongo -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
            <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and this is my servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />



    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="order" value="2" />
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />


</beans:beans>
```

Can someone give me the right way to reach my goal?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

- as @M. Deinum says, i change from `@ModelAttribute` to `@RequestBody` and i add @XmlRootElement(name="mybean" to my bean but spring gives me `httpStatus 415`.
- as @chrylis says, i remove `consumes` annotation leaving `@ModelAttribue` but in this way spring gives me my bean with all null values for each field.

Comment: Just don't do anything. With the default message converters, even without the content-type annotations, Spring will adapt XML and JSON onto the class specified in the method parameter.

Comment: Replace `@ModelAttribute` with `@RequestBody`. If you want XML to work you will haev to add Jaxb annotations on your class else it will not work.

Comment: Changing "@ModelAttribue" to "@RequestBody", adding @XmlRootElement to my bean class and sending an xml with Content-Type: Application/xml, spring gives me "The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method."

Comment: I propose that you break up the `search` method into two methods (one for JSON and one for XML) if you want Spring MVC to automatically convert the input to your POJO. And ofcourse replace `@ModelAttribute` with `@RequestBody`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using `@RequestBody` and adding

```
<beans:bean id="contentManager"
        class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
        <beans:property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
        <beans:property name="useJaf" value="false" />
        <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
            <beans:map>
                <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                <beans:entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentManager" />
```

to my servlet-context.xml